# adding the Duration of all video files in a folder

Tags: linux, shell, video

The following commands gives the duration of all the video files in a folder.

```
ls | grep "[.=]mp4"| xargs -n1 ffmpeg -i  2>&1 | grep Duration | cut -d ' ' -f 4 | sed s/,//
```

Like this

```
00:01:03.96
00:10:10.07
00:04:49.39
00:01:31.63
00:05:32.48
00:04:12.59
00:02:39.79
00:04:14.51
00:07:34.36
00:01:56.08
```

So the question is how to sum all these durations ?

Comment: Better suited for https://unix.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to the end of the pipeline to get duration in seconds:

```
 | awk -F: '{sum += 3600*$1 + 60*$2 + $3} END {print sum}'
```

To get the total duration in seconds. With your sample data, that value is 2624.86

To print in hours:mins:secs, you can do

```
$ date -d @2624.86 -u "+%H:%M:%S.%N"
00:43:44.860000000
```

Or, do that in awk with some arithmetic:

```
| awk -F: '{sum += 3600*$1 + 60*$2 + $3} END {
    hrs = int(sum / 3600)
    sum -= hrs * 3600
    mins = int(sum / 60)
    secs = sum - mins * 60
    printf "%d:%02d:%05.2f\n", hrs, mins, secs
}'
```

Comment: Works perfectly.Thanks